# Why is 'NgTemplateOutlet' needed to access elements within a 'ng-template'? Angular 8

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am working on some unit tests for the ngbDatepicker. Within the ngbDatepicker I use a . But it seems like the ng-template requires the "[ngTemplateOutlet='footerTemplate']" to access elements within the ng-template. Without ngTemplateOutlet the ng-Template isn`t rendered .

Could someone tell me why I need to add ngTemplateOutlet to the ng-template to access elements within the ng-template?

Answer (score 3):

[NgTemplateOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet) is a structural directive which

> Inserts an embedded view from a prepared TemplateRef.

[ng-template](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#the-ng-template) tag is:

> an Angular element for rendering HTML. It is never displayed directly.
>   In fact, before rendering the view, Angular replaces the 
>   and its contents with a comment.

Its important to mention about [ng-container](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue) as well. Which is:

> The Angular  is a grouping element that doesn't
>   interfere with styles or layout because Angular doesn't put it in the
>   DOM.

In simple words if you wanna render something but don't wanna create additional wrapping tag, i.e:

```
<div *ngIf="true">
  <h1>Title</h1>
<div>
```

you need to wrap it in ng-container

```
<ng-container *ngIf="true">
  <h1>Title</h1>
<ng-container>
```

whereas if you wanna create a template for something you need to use ng-template

```
<ng-template #titleTemplate>
  <h1>Title</h1>
<ng-template>
```

its not rendered, this is where NgTemplateOutlet directive comes into play - it will render it

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="titleTemplate"></ng-container>
```

But the power of ngTemplateOutlet is not to render, but to pass a data into ng-template, for example

```
<ng-template #titleTemplate let-title>
  <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
<ng-template>

<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="titleTemplate; context: {$implicit: 'My Title'}"></ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

is not an 'element'. it is rather a rule for building pieces of html. therefore it is not drawn automatically and can be rendered with any directive that do rendering. `<ng-template [ngIf]="true">...` will also work. `ngTemplateOutlet` is a directive designed to render a template. that is why you should use it for some provided template usage.